# Proving that the two topologies are the same

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T$ be two topologies of a set $X$. $X$ is Hausdorff under topology $\mathcal S$ and compact under topology $\mathcal T$. Show that if $\mathcal S$ is finer than $\mathcal T$, then $\mathcal S=\mathcal T$.

My attempt: Two topologies are the same iff the identity map $\mathrm {id}:(X, \mathcal S)\to (X, \mathcal T)$ is a homeomorphism. Clearly this map is continuous since every element of $\mathcal T$ is also an element of $\mathcal S$. However, it doesn't seem easy to prove that the inverse is also continuous.

What should I do?

Comment: What if $S$ is the discrete topology and $T$ is the trivial topology?

Comment: @user49640 Oh, good point. It might be an error of the problem.

Comment: The result is true if $S$ is compact and $T$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: yeah, I proved it just now:)

Comment: See this related MathOverflow post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/15841/1946